File type for Cisco IOS upgrade
Since Cisco is introducing install mode after 9000 series.
There are so many file type
Cisco IOS XE package (.pkg) files
provisioning file (packages.conf)
For .bin and .tar file I think they are both compressed file like a zip on PC
booted Cisco IOSXEsoftwarebundle(.bin) file
Tape Archive (tar) File

The tar contains the .bin and the supporting files for the seldom used web interface

But I am not sure what is the difference between .pkg & packages.conf

https://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/switches/lan/catalyst3850/software/release/3se/consolidated_guide/b_consolidated_3850_3se_cg_chapter_010000010.pdf (for example)
IOS XE can be an oddity. There are two modes of operation: "installed" and "bundled". In the installed mode, there will be pkg files, and a packages.conf "contents" (index of pkgs) in flash. In bundled mode, there will be a single bin file. Bundled mode is the closest to traditional IOS. It's also the slowest way to boot the system, as it has do all the work of "install mode" into RAM.
(The tar file is a bin and a directory tree with the web contents. This is no different from traditional IOS tarballs.)

Cisco IOS XE package (.pkg) files
package file
Provisioning file (packages.conf)
Provisioning file
When the device is running in installed mode, set of package files contained in the booted provisioning file
Cisco IOSXE softwarebundle(.bin) file
When the device is running in bundle mode, the set of package files contained in the booted Cisco IOS XE software bundle
Tape Archive (tar) File
The tar contains the .bin and the supporting files for the seldom used web interface
